# Failing to install MIME::Base64 using cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

Please help me to install
[MIME::Base64](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Base64)
using cpan

I'm getting the following error message:

```
[root@vmi125816 ~]# cpan use MIME::Base64;
Reading '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 30 Jun 2017 23:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'use'
Running make for A/AU/AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AU/AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building A/AU/AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz

Cannot determine license info from lib/use.pm
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for use
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/use/perl5.pm blib/lib/use/perl5.pm
cp lib/use.pm blib/lib/use.pm
Manifying 2 pod documents
  AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/0-signature.t .. ok
t/1-basic.t ...... Undefined subroutine &main::ok called at t/1-basic.t line 2.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 before it could output anything.
t/1-basic.t ...... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/1-basic.t    (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 1 tests but ran 0.
Files=2, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.08 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/2 test programs. 0/1 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports AUDREYT/use-0.05.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
MIME::Base64 is up to date (3.15).
[root@vmi125816 ~]#
```

Comment: Are you really typing `cpan use MIME::Base64`? I would suggest using `cpan MIME::Base64`.

Comment: And you might be missing build tools (build-essential, gcc,...)? You could also install via package manager e.g. apt-get install libmime-base64-perl.

Answer (score 1):

You are encountering an error installing the module named `use`, a module you accidentally asked to install by doing

```
cpan use MIME::Base64
```

instead of

```
cpan MIME::Base64
```

Since you don't need the module anyway, it doesn't matter that it's buggy. Just run the correct command.